# How are you supposed to read the following documentation?

Tags: c++, com

From [`IDispatch::GetTypeInfoCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221674.aspx)

> The return value obtained from the
>   returned HRESULT is one of the
>   following: [S_OK -> Success],
>   [E_NOTIMPL -> Failure]

And the sample at the bottom returns `E_INVALIDARG` and `NOERROR`.

As far as I see `E_INVALIDARG` is not `S_OK`, nor is it `NOERROR`, so what do you do? Do you check for invalid pointers or you don't?

It seems that COM is pretty much foundation for everything, and I can't find one good source of information about correct behavior of simple `IDispatch`. How do you approach such inconsistencies in your production code?

Comment: COM is not the foundation of everything.  Quite the opposite, it is becoming more irrelevant over time.

Comment: Whenever I read questions like "how are we supposed to..?" it always reminds me of a friend answering "carefully, my friend, carefully"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With COM, you should never check for specific return values unless you actually need to have special handling for those values. Instead, you should use the FAILED or SUCCEEDED macros when you just need to know if a call failed or succeeded. i.e.

```
HRESULT hr = ...;
if (FAILED(hr)) {
   ...
```

COM calls can often return a much wider range of error codes than is specified in the documentation. The called function is not the only source of errors. Depending on the call is actually made (in-process, out-of-process, DCOM) the COM system itself can return a whole host of errors.

Comment: But what if I'm implementing the IDispatch? The documentation says I should return either S_OK, or E_NOTIMPL, that is, there is no error state at all, except missing implementation, in which case client should fall back to other routines. But if client sees E_RNDOM it might as well crash with access violation?

Comment: So why do the docs say "the return value is either S_OK or E_NOTIMPL". Shouldn't there be a footnote somewhere saying something like "just kidding ^_^. Actually, it can be anything.."?

Comment: @Luther Blissett: The docs just can't repeat the obvious things. What if you pass a null pointer? Should it return `S_OK` or `E_NOTIMPL`? Obviously it should return something else specific to null pointers.

Comment: Or maybe `S_FALSE`? `SUCCEEDED(S_FALSE) == true`?

Comment: So why is there a description of the return values anyway? How are S_OK and E_NOTIMPL less obvious thank E_INVALIDARG?

Comment: @Luther Blissett: They wanted to say "typically this method is either implemented and returns `S_OK` or not implemented and returns `E_NOTIMPL`" meaning that there's nothing like `S_FALSE` meaning anything special.

Comment: @Coder: Yes, `SUCCEEDED(S_FALSE)==true` - anything that starts with `S_` evaluates `SUCCEEDED` to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

`NOERROR` is defined to the very same value as `S_OK`. Checking for a null pointer before dereferencing is good style in any method but in this sample it should return `E_POINTER`.

Values `NOERROR`/`S_OK` and `E_NOTIMPL` are the most typical you should expect from that method unless you abuse the method, that list can of course omit codes like `E_POINTER`.

Anyway don't target for specific codes, use `SUCCEEDED`/`FAILED` macros.